# Can't read text file and can't find a solution

Tags: java, android

I've tried many methods of reading files and I have found that none of them work. I am not using the default libraries. I'm using a framework that is found from [here](http://www.kilobolt.com/create-an-android-game-from-scratch-or-port-your-existing-game.html)

I'm trying to read it and insert it line by line into a String array. Every method I've tried requires a Context, but because this is not initialized the same way as a default android application, it doesn't have a context to use getAssets. Is there any other way of reading a text file?

I tried using this set of code, but it didn't work because it required assets.

```
    InputStream iS;
    resources = AndroidGame.resources;

    if (loadFromRawFolder) {
        int rID = resources.getIdentifier("raw/store_app", "raw", "com.cciamlazy.pixunited");
        iS = resources.openRawResource(rID);
    } else {
        iS = resources.getAssets().open(inFile);
    }
    byte[] buffer = new byte[iS.available()];
    iS.read(buffer);
    ByteArrayOutputStream oS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    oS.write(buffer);
    oS.close();
    iS.close();
```

This code gives me errors and the resources `!= null`. Gives me the error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
```

Full class code

```
package com.cciamlazy.pixunited;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;


public class MapLoader extends Activity {

    private static Resources resources;

    public MapLoader() {
        resources = getResources();
    }

    public static String LoadFile(String fileName, boolean loadFromRawFolder) throws IOException {

        // Create a InputStream to read the file into
        InputStream iS;

        if (loadFromRawFolder) {
            // get the resource id from the file name
            // int rID = resources.getIdentifier(fileName, null, null);
            int rID = resources.getIdentifier("raw/store_app", "raw",
                    "com.cciamlazy.activity");
            // get the file as a stream
            iS = resources.openRawResource(rID);
        } else {
            // get the file as a stream
            iS = resources.getAssets().open(fileName);
        }

        // create a buffer that has the same size as the InputStream
        byte[] buffer = new byte[iS.available()];
        // read the text file as a stream, into the buffer
        iS.read(buffer);
        // create a output stream to write the buffer into
        ByteArrayOutputStream oS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // write this buffer to the output stream
        oS.write(buffer);
        // Close the Input and Output streams
        oS.close();
        iS.close();

        // return the output stream as a String
        return oS.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: post some code please

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.....

add these two lines to your activity

```
private static Resources resources;

resources = getResources();
```

After that add this method.

```
 public static String LoadFile(String fileName, boolean loadFromRawFolder)


            throws IOException {

        // Create a InputStream to read the file into
        InputStream iS;

        if (loadFromRawFolder) {
            // get the resource id from the file name
            // int rID = resources.getIdentifier(fileName, null, null);
            int rID = resources.getIdentifier("raw/store_app", "raw",
                    "com.example.activity");
            // get the file as a stream
            iS = resources.openRawResource(rID);
        } else {
            // get the file as a stream
            iS = resources.getAssets().open(fileName);
        }

        // create a buffer that has the same size as the InputStream
        byte[] buffer = new byte[iS.available()];
        // read the text file as a stream, into the buffer
        iS.read(buffer);
        // create a output stream to write the buffer into
        ByteArrayOutputStream oS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // write this buffer to the output stream
        oS.write(buffer);
        // Close the Input and Output streams
        oS.close();
        iS.close();

        // return the output stream as a String
        return oS.toString();
    }
```

Comment: "resources" is not a variable in my case.

Comment: I can't use getResources due to the fact that I am not using the normal framework for android applications. I don't use res and even when I import it I get that I have to create a method called getResources

Comment: what do you mean by normal framework?I really don't understand.I think before doing some coding please read the android developer site.You can full copy and paste your code here.That will be helpful for anyone.

Comment: I updated what code I have and it still gives me errors

Comment: Can't you paste full class? Is it a activity or fragment or other ?

Comment: Other and I posted the code for the class

Comment: you have to extends some class, like fragment or activity or application something otherwise  it will be no use.

Comment: I created new class to do it and I posted it above and it's still crashing my application giving me the error, "java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"